# Use of infrasonic waves as vehicle security measures

Tags: internal-consistency, technology

Is the use of infrasonic waves possible in the same way ultrasonic waves are used in vehicle sensors?

It would have more benefits. For example, infrasound travels for longer distances, and thus it can tell if the vehicle's driver is at risk of colliding with an object 250/500 meters away in weather that would affect visibility (e.g a sandstorm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few major issues.

The first is that the sensors would have to be bigger.  The longer the wavelength of your signal, the larger the receiver needs to be to couple with the signal well.  This is a very noticeable effect in the human ear where we like to power sub woofers with 1000W+ amplifiers to get to the "oomph" we want, while the tweeters only need to be powered with 1W!

The second is the bandwidth.  Vehicles need to deconflict to make sure they aren't confusing their signal with someone else's.  At high frequencies, you can get a lot of signal into a small time period and small portion of the bandwidth.  At low frequencies, you need to chew up the entire band for longer, resulting in easy conflicts.

The third issue I can think of is angular resolution.  I'm not 100% certain how all vehicle sensors today do angle detection, but many of the techniques (such as monopulse angles) are more effective at higher frequencies.  With infrasonics, you could be certain that there is an object 100m away from you, but you couldn't be certain whether it is in front of you or off to the side!

Comment: C₁ (the lowest C on the piano keyboard), 32.7 Hz, already has a wavelength (in air) of 10.5 meters. C₀ (the lowest audible C), 16.4 Hz, has a wavelength of 21 meters. Objects with dimensions much smaller than the wavelength of the sound pulse (such as, for example, cars and pedestrians) will be completely invisible on a sonar using infrasounds. But such an infrasonar it will be very good at detecting mountains and possibly large hills.